# how to insert Node Q into a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, insertion

So, considering the following conditions, is this correct:

conditions:

- prev references the last node of the list
- curr is null

  ```
  public void insertQ(SinglyLinkedListNode Q){
      if (prev.next.next == curr){
          prev.next = Q;
          Q.next = curr;
      }
      return;
  }
  ```

Does the previous statement insert node Q into a linked list properly?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand your logic in adding a node to the end of a singly linked list. Your line `if (prev.next.next == curr)` is undefined as prev.next is itself `null`. I have added a snippet for adding a node in the end of a linked list.

```
void append(int data){

    Node node = new Node(data);
    if(head==null){
         head = new Node(int data);
         return;
    }
    new_node.next = null;
    Node last = head; 
    while (last.next != null)
        last = last.next;

    last.next = new_node;
    return;
}
```